# Add/removing div block jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a script to add div block after clicking the add button.
Everything is fine, however after adding second block that incrementing.

For example: After second clicking that adding 4 block overall 6.

After clicking the removing that is deleting the last one also.

```
var removeBtn = $("#removeField");
$("body").on("click", "#addField", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var room = $(".room-type").first();
  var count = removeBtn.data("count");

  if (count > 0) {
    removeBtn.data("count", count++).attr("data-count", count++);
  } else {
    removeBtn.data("count", 1).attr("data-count", 1);
  }

  room.clone(false).appendTo(".room-type");
});

$("body").on("click", "#removeField:not([data-count=0])", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var count = removeBtn.data("count");

  if (count > 0) {

    $(".room-type").data("count", count--).attr("data-count", count--).last().remove();
  }
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="form_element select room-type">

    <div class="duo_left">
    <label class="form_name"><?=pll__('Room type')?></label>
    <select name="room-type[]" class="selectpicker multi-fields">
    <?if($single != null) :?>
    <option value="Single Room">Single Room</option>
<? endif; ?>
<?if($double != null) :?>
<option value="Single Room">Double Room</option>
<? endif; ?>
<?if($deluxe != null) :?>
<option value="Single Room">Deluxe Room</option>
<? endif; ?>
<?if($deluxe_double != null) :?>
<option value="Single Room">Deluxe Double Room</option>
<? endif; ?>
<?if($executive_room != null) :?>
<option value="Single Room">Deluxe Double Room</option>
<? endif; ?>
<?if($gloria_room != null) :?>
<option value="Single Room">Gloria Room</option>
<? endif; ?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="duo_right">
<label class="form_name"><?=pll__('Number')?></label>
<select name="room-number[]" class="selectpicker multi-fields">
<option value="0" selected>0</option>
<? for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) : ?>
<option value="<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></option>
<? endfor; ?>
<option value="10+">10+</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume calling `count++` and `count--` twice in a single statement adds and detracts twice each time. Try to only manipulate the `count` one time and use it's value instead. Such as `if (count > 0) {count++; removeBtn.data("count", count).attr("data-count", count);}`

Comment: Share your html or create fiddle

Comment: bookanytravel.com/hotel/city-palace-hotel-tashkent/#rooms  In rooms tab you can see room type which I am trying to fix

Comment: Do you want to add 1 row at a time? or clone the number of rows already present? ex: if 2 are present on next add you want to make total count 4? or 3?

Comment: Yes sir you right, I want to add 1 row. total count 3

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/11/

Comment: yes sir thanks, however remove button also delete the first one also

Comment: added an answer with updated Remove functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to append to a parent div, add an additional div

like "container" on top of your "room-type"
and append your clone to it

```
room.clone().appendTo("#container");
```

also before removing check the length of your "room-type" class

here is a working fiddle for you

https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/12/

Comment: thanks I updated my code you can see by this link bookanytravel.com/hotel/city-palace-hotel-tashkent/#rooms
I have last question can I do that without adding additional div or to put that somewhere in there form

Comment: I don't see container div in your html on that link? you need to add that before your 1st room-type class and end it before the div with class buttons, without that div this code won't work, updated the fiddle with comments https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/13/

Comment: Now you can check the link additional div can broke my css

Comment: there has to be some issue with you HTML itself then.... adding a div to the code you provided should not break anything

Comment: thanks for your spending time, you gave overall ready solution. Now I will try to find solution for html. It will be the best if no adding any additional div